# How do I fetch a part of html page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image: This is the output of alert box]I am trying to fetch a div element of class "mno" from abc.php into xyz.php

http://pastebin.com/MhAqhZpd has the code I'm using (not the entire code only ajax part)

The url points to the script but the second alert box does not display anything, not even "NULL" - also console.log gives nothing. I am new  to ajax so may be missing sumthing trivial thanks in advance

Comment: $('div') will return div in the document, not in the string argument you're passing.  You'd also better read what `.html()` does.

Comment: I know that thts why my abc.php conatains only those elemnts within html tags which I want to load

Comment: The fact that you're saying this demonstrates that you have no idea how jQuery selectors work, or simply didn't read what `.html()` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use http://api.jquery.com/load/ if the file you want to acces is in the same server.

```
$("div").load("abc.php div.mno");
```

Comment: if I do this then div of xyz.php will be replaced by div.mno selector of abc.php?

Comment: all div of xyz.php will contain every element from the selector from the file abc.php. But you should assign an ID to your div.mno and use  the ID as selector. Maybe you should do the same thing with your xyz.php div selector.

Comment: I mean. add an ID to div.mno if there is only 1 in the abc you want to retrieve. Same for the div from the xyz file if you want just to put only in this div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery load method. The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows you to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

```
$('div').load('abc.php div.mno');
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can go like this: (i'm sticking to what you question is saying !)

```
$.get('abc.php',function(data){
    var mnoDivHTML = $(data).find('div.mno').html(); //the html content of .mno div in abc.php
    $('div.yourclass').html(mnoDivHTML); //fill the desired div in the current page
});
```

Comment: this is supposed to replace content of my class with content of div.mno from abc.php??

Answer (score 1):

`$.load()` is great if you don't mind it being quite inflexible, but if you want something a little more powerful you can actually use `$.get` or `$.post`.

Example:

```
var data = {'someParam':'someValue'};
$.post('abc.php', data, function(response){
    var myDiv = $('.mno', response); //get class .mno from response text
    alert(myDiv.html());
});
```

This can be pretty neat if for instance you are using it to get the next page of search results, so you would want to pass in parameters to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:) Just replace load.html with your document and div you want to load like : mypage.php .somediv

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

$(document).ready(function(){
//var ajax = function(url){
//var url = 'load.html';
//$('.content').load(url);
//}
// Than you call it like THIS: ajax();
//$('.button').click(function(){
//$('.content').load('load.html')
//});
//response contains the text content that was returned from the ajax request
$(".content").load('load.html', function(response, error, xhr) {
if (error == "error") {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);


}
});
});
});
</script>
```